# Getting json response by setting credentials for secure connection in restlet

Tags: java, authentication, https, restlet

This is the simplest code I can have:

```
ClientResource resource = new  ClientResource("https://www.myTestSite.com/requests");
resource.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.
HTTP_BASIC, "kladhfklahghlsgkagdkh", "jgasdkjbvjkagjhgajkb");
// Send the request
try {
resource.get();
} catch (ResourceException re) {
}
// Should be 200
System.out.println(resource.getStatus());
```

**Error Log:**

```
  Apr 21, 2015 7:04:01 PM org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpClientHelper start
    INFO: Starting the internal HTTP client
    Apr 21, 2015 7:04:04 PM org.restlet.resource.ClientResource retry
    INFO: A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
    Apr 21, 2015 7:04:07 PM org.restlet.resource.ClientResource retry
    INFO: A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
    Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 32 more
```

**NOTE:**

- I am able to hit the URL (https://www.myTestSite.com/requests) in
  Firefox which then asks for a username and password. I fill it and I
  get the json response.
- I am able to get the json response by using curl command as well.

  `curl -u kladhfklahghlsgkagdkh:jgasdkjbvjkagjhgajkb -X GET https://www.myTestSite.com/requests`

So it is working through browser and curl but not using restlet.

**My response header:**

```
Status Code         : 200 OK
Content-Encoding    : gzip
Content-Type        : application/json; charset=utf-8
Date                : Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:30:48 GMT
Etag                : W/"919-1189182981"
Server              : Apache
Vary                : X-HTTP-Method-Override
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the certificate of your test website is self-signed. In such case, you need to import this certificate in Java. See this link for more details: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/https.

Hope it helps you and will help you to fix your issue,
Thierry